# Difference between IS NULL criteria in JOIN and WHERE in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

```
create table #t1 (id int)
create table #t2 (id int)

insert into #t1 values (1)
insert into #t1 values (2)
insert into #t1 values (3)

insert into #t2 values (1)
insert into #t2 values (2)
```

I ran the below queries, and I get 2 different outputs.

Second is the desired output.

I cannot understand the reason for output given by  query1.

Please assist me to understand the result.

```
-- Query1

select * from #t1 a left join #t2 b on a.id = b.id and  b.id is null

-- Query2

select * from #t1 a left join #t2 b on a.id = b.id where b.id is null
```

Comment: first one takes two condition on join. second one has one condition on join where b.id is null.

Comment: Query1 uses a 'JOIN' criteria in a left join: the condition works as a match, whereas Query2 uses the condition as a filter.

Comment: Those queries are maybe similar but absolutely not the same. It is important to understand the difference. There are enough sources to learn sql.

Comment: For all join types please have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In query 1 we have `b.id is null` in join criteria, which because being `LEFT JOIN` on A returns all rows of A irrespective of JOIN criteria and therefore **returns 3 rows for table  A**.

In query 2 first `LEFT JOIN` on A returns 3 rows and then `where b.id is null` is applied on these 3 rows which  leaves the third row and results in **only 1 rows** for the third row for id=3 .

**Further explanation:**

Your comment

> Though in Query1 how come b.id is null ??

requires detailed explanation

as I said in Query 1 for each row of A there is a row returned in Left join **irrespective of criteria of JOIN**

so your join criteria is actually

**a.id = b.id and  b.id is null**

a logical **And**  between two criteria which cannot be true simultaneously as if **b.id is null** is true then a.id=null is being matched which is basically null

output is given here in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c20ba/1

and is like

```
id  | id
________
 1  |  null
 2  |  null
 3  |  null
```

**Another point to note:** Do note that in SQL `id=NULL` is evaluated as `NULL`. Also note that when doing logical operations like AND OR in sql query, NULL behaves quite peculiarly. See the [msdn documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196106(v=sql.80).aspx) on this behavior

```
null and true = null
null and false=false
null and null =null
null or null =null
null or true= true
null or false=null
```

Comment: Though in Query1 how come b.id is null ??

Comment: @DhruvJoshi it's the other way around. Query2 only returns the last row where a.id=3

Comment: @NickyvV corrected. Thank you for pointing out my proof of hastiness. Doing the walk of shame now, away from laptop. poof!

Answer (score 2):

This one is not correct:

```
select *
from
  #t1 a left join #t2 b
  on a.id = b.id and b.id is null
```

you want `b.id` to be null AND, at the same time, to be `b.id = a.id`. This can never be true, so the join will not succeed. You will get all rows from #t1 table but all null values for #t2.

This one is correct:

```
select *
from
  #t1 a left join #t2 b
  on a.id = b.id
where
  b.id is null
```

you are using a LEFT JOIN, so your query will return all rows from #t1 and only the rows from #t2 where the join succeeds (and it will succeed when `a.id = b.id`).

When the join doesn't succeed, `b.id` will be set to null. Using `WHERE b.id is null` you will get only the rows where the join won't succeed and you will get all values from #t1 which are not present in #t2.

You can try to run this query to see what's actually happening and to better understand the logic:

```
select *
from
  #t1 a left join #t2 b
  on a.id = b.id
```